# Magento 2 - Add a new product attribute with values from DB

Tags: magento2, database, model, eav

I'm looking for creating a custom attribute for products, already have a CRUD module, with name and descriptions fields, so the names from my DB should be options of that attribute.
How do I need to correct this code, so it will get values from my DB? Thanks everyone!

```
class Material extends \Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\Source\AbstractSource
{
    /**
     * Get all options
     * @return array
     */
    public function getAllOptions()
    {
        if (!$this->_options) {
            $this->_options = [
                ['label' => __('Cotton'), 'value' => 'cotton'],
                ['label' => __('Leather'), 'value' => 'leather'],
                ['label' => __('Silk'), 'value' => 'silk'],
                ['label' => __('Denim'), 'value' => 'denim'],
                ['label' => __('Fur'), 'value' => 'fur'],
                ['label' => __('Wool'), 'value' => 'wool'],
            ];
        }
        return $this->_options;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So I figured out, how to get options for my custom attribute, from DB table, here is how my class in Source/Vendors.php looks now:

class Vendors extends \Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\Source\AbstractSource
{
    protected $collectionFactory;

```
public function __construct(CollectionFactory $collectionFactory)
{
    $this->collectionFactory = $collectionFactory;
}

/**
 * Get all options
 * @return array
 */
public function getAllOptions()
{
    if (!$this->_options) {
        /** @var Collection $collection */
        $collection = $this->collectionFactory->create();

        $vendors = $collection->getItems();

        if (!$vendors) {
            return [];
        }

        $options = [];

        foreach ($vendors as $vendor) {
            $options[] = [
                'label' => $vendor->getData('name'),
                'value' => $vendor->getData('name')
            ];
        }

        $this->_options = $options;
    }

    return $this->_options;
}
```